# How to change the label when coupon is applied?

Tags: magento

This is what I want to change

[image: click to see the image]

I want to change the `extra fee` label to `discount`.

Can't seem to find out how to do it anywhere.

Comment: check this template file yourproject\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\total\default.phtml. if you are working on magento2

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to solve this problem.

The first option is to change "extra fee" to "discount" following official instruction Translation overview from Magento. It was done to localize the webstore for different regions, but you can translate extra fee to discount. You need a translation dictionary which is a comma-separated value (.csv) file with at two columns: the original phrase and a translation of that phrase. The whole instruction is here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

The second option is to create your own module and override `Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Address\Attribute\Fronten\Discount` class where you can rewrite `fetchTotals()` method by substituting your value in the `$title` variable.